# GoogleTest gives error checking vector<reference_wrapper<T>>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl, c++17, googletest

We have a `TEST` containing this exact code (originally `string` was a custom type but I made a new test with `string` to verify it still failed):

```
std::string s1("aaa"), s2("bbb"), s3("ccc");
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>> vec;
vec.push_back(std::ref(s1));
vec.push_back(std::ref(s2));
vec.push_back(std::ref(s3));
EXPECT_THAT(vec, ElementsAre(
    std::reference_wrapper<std::string>(s1),
    std::reference_wrapper<std::string>(s2),
    std::reference_wrapper<std::string>(s3)));
```

This code previously compiled under VS2017 (v141, c++11) with GTest 1.8.1 but against VS2019 (v142, c++17) and GTest 1.11 we get the most *beautiful* error message, shown in full wonder below.

A `vector` of `references_wrappers` seems a *little* odd but not unprecedented. I'm trying to figure out why it compiled before and now it doesn't. Why does `ElementsAre` hate it?

Note for those wondering why I test this, in our actual code-test `vec` is returned by the function we want to test e.g:

```
x.Add(std::string("aaa"));
x.Add(std::string("bbb"));
x.Add(std::string("ccc")); 
auto vec = x.Get();
```

But my exact test above gives the same error so it's simpler to reproduce.

```
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(179,49): error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const A' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
        with
        [
            A=Element
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest.h(1536,13): message : could be 'bool testing::internal::operator ==(testing::internal::faketype,testing::internal::faketype)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\exception(267,28): message : or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,const std::exception_ptr &) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\exception(271,28): message : or       'bool std::operator ==(std::nullptr_t,const std::exception_ptr &) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\exception(275,28): message : or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,std::nullptr_t) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\system_error(168,28): message : or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_code &) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\system_error(172,28): message : or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\system_error(176,28): message : or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\system_error(248,28): message : or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\thread(204,24): message : or       'bool std::operator ==(std::thread::id,std::thread::id) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(179,49): message : while trying to match the argument list '(const A, const B)'
        with
        [
            A=Element
        ]
        and
        [
            B=std::string
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(716): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool testing::internal::AnyEq::operator ()<Lhs,T>(const A &,const B &) const' being compiled
        with
        [
            Lhs=Element,
            T=std::string,
            A=Element,
            B=std::string
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(352): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool testing::internal::ComparisonBase<testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>,Rhs,testing::internal::AnyEq>::MatchAndExplain<Element>(const Lhs &,std::ostream *) const' being compiled
        with
        [
            Rhs=Element,
            Lhs=Element
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(352): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool testing::internal::ComparisonBase<testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>,Rhs,testing::internal::AnyEq>::MatchAndExplain<Element>(const Lhs &,std::ostream *) const' being compiled
        with
        [
            Rhs=Element,
            Lhs=Element
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(392): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool testing::internal::MatcherBase<T>::MatchAndExplainImpl<P>(const testing::internal::MatcherBase<T> &,T,testing::MatchResultListener *)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=const Element &,
            P=Policy
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(392): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool testing::internal::MatcherBase<T>::MatchAndExplainImpl<P>(const testing::internal::MatcherBase<T> &,T,testing::MatchResultListener *)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=const Element &,
            P=Policy
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(464): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'const testing::internal::MatcherBase<T>::VTable *testing::internal::MatcherBase<T>::GetVTable<Policy>(void)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=const Element &
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(464): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'const testing::internal::MatcherBase<T>::VTable *testing::internal::MatcherBase<T>::GetVTable<Policy>(void)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=const Element &
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(298): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void testing::internal::MatcherBase<T>::Init<_Ty>(M &&)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=const Element &,
            _Ty=testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>,
            M=testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(298): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void testing::internal::MatcherBase<T>::Init<_Ty>(M &&)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=const Element &,
            _Ty=testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>,
            M=testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(499): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::internal::MatcherBase<T>::MatcherBase<_Ty,testing::internal::ComparisonBase<testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>,Rhs,testing::internal::AnyEq>::is_gtest_matcher>(M &&)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=const Element &,
            _Ty=testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>,
            Rhs=Element,
            M=testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(499): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::internal::MatcherBase<T>::MatcherBase<_Ty,testing::internal::ComparisonBase<testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>,Rhs,testing::internal::AnyEq>::is_gtest_matcher>(M &&)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=const Element &,
            _Ty=testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>,
            Rhs=Element,
            M=testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(880): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::Matcher<const Element &>::Matcher<testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>,testing::internal::ComparisonBase<testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>,Rhs,testing::internal::AnyEq>::is_gtest_matcher>(M &&)' being compiled
        with
        [
            Rhs=Element,
            M=testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(880): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::Matcher<const Element &>::Matcher<testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>,testing::internal::ComparisonBase<testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>,Rhs,testing::internal::AnyEq>::is_gtest_matcher>(M &&)' being compiled
        with
        [
            Rhs=Element,
            M=testing::internal::EqMatcher<Element>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gtest\gtest-matchers.h(880): message : while compiling class template member function 'testing::Matcher<const Element &>::Matcher(T)'
        with
        [
            T=const Element &
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(368): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::Matcher<const Element &>::Matcher(T)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=const Element &
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(352): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::Matcher<const Element &> testing::internal::MatcherCastImpl<T,M>::CastImpl<true>(const M &,std::true_type,std::integral_constant<bool,true>)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=const Element &,
            M=std::reference_wrapper<std::string>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(350): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::Matcher<const Element &> testing::internal::MatcherCastImpl<T,M>::CastImpl<true>(const M &,std::true_type,std::integral_constant<bool,true>)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=const Element &,
            M=std::reference_wrapper<std::string>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(336): message : while compiling class template member function 'testing::Matcher<const Element &> testing::internal::MatcherCastImpl<T,M>::Cast(const M &)'
        with
        [
            T=const Element &,
            M=std::reference_wrapper<std::string>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(510): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::Matcher<const Element &> testing::internal::MatcherCastImpl<T,M>::Cast(const M &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=const Element &,
            M=std::reference_wrapper<std::string>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(510): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::MatcherCastImpl<T,M>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=const Element &,
            M=std::reference_wrapper<std::string>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(3523): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::Matcher<const Element &> testing::MatcherCast<Target,Arg>(const M &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            Target=const Element &,
            Arg=std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,
            M=std::reference_wrapper<std::string>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(718): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::Matcher<const Element &> testing::internal::CastAndAppendTransform<const Element &>::operator ()<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>(const Arg &) const' being compiled
        with
        [
            Arg=std::reference_wrapper<std::string>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(718): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::Matcher<const Element &> testing::internal::CastAndAppendTransform<const Element &>::operator ()<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>(const Arg &) const' being compiled
        with
        [
            Arg=std::reference_wrapper<std::string>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(717): message : while compiling class template member function 'OutIter testing::internal::TransformTupleValuesHelper<Tuple,Func,OutIter>::IterateOverTuple<Tuple,3>::operator ()(Func,const Tup &,OutIter) const'
        with
        [
            OutIter=std::back_insert_iterator<MatcherVec>,
            Tuple=std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>,
            Func=testing::internal::CastAndAppendTransform<const Element &>,
            Tup=std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(711): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'OutIter testing::internal::TransformTupleValuesHelper<Tuple,Func,OutIter>::IterateOverTuple<Tuple,3>::operator ()(Func,const Tup &,OutIter) const' being compiled
        with
        [
            OutIter=std::back_insert_iterator<MatcherVec>,
            Tuple=std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>,
            Func=testing::internal::CastAndAppendTransform<const Element &>,
            Tup=std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(711): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::TransformTupleValuesHelper<Tuple,Func,OutIter>::IterateOverTuple<Tuple,3>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Tuple=std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>,
            Func=testing::internal::CastAndAppendTransform<const Element &>,
            OutIter=std::back_insert_iterator<MatcherVec>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(710): message : while compiling class template member function 'OutIter testing::internal::TransformTupleValuesHelper<Tuple,Func,OutIter>::Run(Func,const Tuple &,OutIter)'
        with
        [
            OutIter=std::back_insert_iterator<MatcherVec>,
            Tuple=std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>,
            Func=testing::internal::CastAndAppendTransform<const Element &>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(735): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'OutIter testing::internal::TransformTupleValuesHelper<Tuple,Func,OutIter>::Run(Func,const Tuple &,OutIter)' being compiled
        with
        [
            OutIter=std::back_insert_iterator<MatcherVec>,
            Tuple=std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>,
            Func=testing::internal::CastAndAppendTransform<const Element &>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(735): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::TransformTupleValuesHelper<Tuple,Func,OutIter>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Tuple=std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>,
            Func=testing::internal::CastAndAppendTransform<const Element &>,
            OutIter=std::back_insert_iterator<MatcherVec>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(3574): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'OutIter testing::internal::TransformTupleValues<MatcherTuple,testing::internal::CastAndAppendTransform<const Element &>,std::back_insert_iterator<MatcherVec>>(Func,const Tuple &,OutIter)' being compiled
        with
        [
            OutIter=std::back_insert_iterator<MatcherVec>,
            MatcherTuple=std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>,
            Func=testing::internal::CastAndAppendTransform<const Element &>,
            Tuple=std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(368): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcher<std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>::operator testing::Matcher<const T &>(void) const<const T&>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(368): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcher<std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>::operator testing::Matcher<const T &>(void) const<const T&>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(352): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::Matcher<const T &> testing::internal::MatcherCastImpl<const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>&,M>::CastImpl<false>(const M &,std::true_type,std::integral_constant<bool,false>)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>,
            M=testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcher<std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(350): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::Matcher<const T &> testing::internal::MatcherCastImpl<const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>&,M>::CastImpl<false>(const M &,std::true_type,std::integral_constant<bool,false>)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>,
            M=testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcher<std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(336): message : while compiling class template member function 'testing::Matcher<const T &> testing::internal::MatcherCastImpl<const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>&,M>::Cast(const M &)'
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>,
            M=testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcher<std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(510): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::Matcher<const T &> testing::internal::MatcherCastImpl<const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>&,M>::Cast(const M &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>,
            M=testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcher<std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(510): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::MatcherCastImpl<T,M>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>> &,
            M=testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcher<std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(517): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::Matcher<const T &> testing::MatcherCast<const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>&,M>(const M &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>,
            M=testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcher<std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>
        ]
c:\vcpkg\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(1534): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::Matcher<const T &> testing::SafeMatcherCast<const T&,M>(const M &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>,
            M=testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcher<std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>
        ]
c:\code\test.cpp(94): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::PredicateFormatterFromMatcher<testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcher<std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>>::operator ()<std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>>(const char *,const T &) const' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>
        ]
c:\code\test.cpp(94): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::PredicateFormatterFromMatcher<testing::internal::ElementsAreMatcher<std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>>::operator ()<std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>>(const char *,const T &) const' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>>
        ]
```

Comment: Just making sure, You have `#include <functional>` in the code right?

Comment: `std::reference_wrapper` doesn't provide `operator==` is what the error is saying, I believe.

Comment: I've explicitly added it to check, no difference @NathanOliver

Comment: Simpler repro: `std::string s; std::ref(s) == std::ref(s);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that seems to be the case (that it doesn't have the operator). But then why did it compile previously? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper

Comment: My guess would be, the earlier implementation incorrectly provided `operator==`

Comment: I don't think it would change much, but why not compare the elements in the vector to the strings directly?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number e.g. `EXPECT_EQ(ByRef(s1), vec[0]);` ?

Comment: i meant `EXPECT_THAT(vec,ElementsAre(s1,s2,s3));`, but I guess you'd get very similar error

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I did try that and yes the same issue